# Managing document embeded inside one mongoose model. Reading and Updating

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a user talent document in mongoose for my application (Nodejs). All users will add their talent along with some **media** files. I embed this **media** file inside my **talent** model as an array. Now the models will looks like:

user-talent.js

```
{
    userId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: "Users" },
    category: { type: String, required: true, ref: "Category" },
    level: { type: String, required: true },
    description: { type: String },
    media: [
      {
        file: { type: String },
        fileType: { type: String },
        description: { type: String },
        caption: { type: String },
        adminApproved: { type: Number, default: 0 },
        status: { type: Number, default: 0 },
      },
    ],
    chars: {
      instruments: { type: Array},
      films: { type: Number},
      years: { type: Number },
      songs: { type: Number },
    }
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

Now the problem is I need only the media document where the **adminApproved is 1**

When I tried:

```
Talent.find({userId: ObjectId(req.user._id), "media.adminApproved": {$eq: 1}})
```

It returned a null array.

And, I need to access this media by the **_id** and need to update the *adminApproved* to 1 from admin. It also returned a **null**

Is it possible???

Comment: Have you tried `Talent.find({userId: ObjectId(req.user._id), "media.adminApproved": 1})
` ?

Comment: Yes, it will return the media document which have adminApproved is 0 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) to return only `adminApproved` media. You can use additional condition to filter by media `_id`:

```
let result = await Talent.aggregate([
    { $match: { userId: ObjectId(req.user._id) } },
    {
        $addFields: {
            media: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$media",
                    cond: {
                        $eq: [ "$$this.adminApproved", 1 ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "categories",
            localField: "category",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "category"
        }
    }
])
```

[The $ positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) can be used to set the `adminApproved` flag:

```
await Talent.updateOne({ userId: ObjectId(req.user._id), "media._id": mediaId }, { $set: "media.$.adminApproved": 1 })
```

Comment: This one is working but I'm having another error now. Coz I'm using ref inside this talent model to category model. How to join this? .populate is showing error.

Comment: @LijomonCJohn you need to replace your populates with `$lookups` (see my modified example for categories). Make sure MongoDB store your relationship in `categories` collection (pluralizes model names by default)

Comment: Thank mickl that solved my issue. If i have three documents named, _categories_, _talents_ and _medias_ and **talent refs category** and **media refs talent**. I want to get talent by populating with category and media. Like: talent: {_id: "..", level: "..", category: { _id: "..", title: ".."}, media: [{ _id: "..", file: ".."}]}